# DKIM signing – duplicate header signing in DKIM-Signature

Tags: dkim, rspamd

My e-mail messages are DKIM signed but I noticed that the `DKIM-Signature` header contains duplicated header indicators like:

```
h=from:from:subject:subject:date:date:message-id:message-id:to:to: […]
```

and so on, while I typically receive from others signed messages with indicators like:

```
h=Date:Subject:From:To;
```

In my case signing is done using `rspamd` and the `local.d/dkim_signing.conf` file contains line with

```
sign_headers = "(o)from:(x)sender:(x)reply-to:(o)subject:(x)date:(x)message-id:(o)to:(o)cc:(x)mime-version:(x)content-type:(x)content-transfer-encoding:resent-to:resent-cc:resent-from:resent-sender:resent-message-id:(x)in-reply-to:(x)references:list-id:list-help:list-owner:list-unsubscribe:list-unsubscribe-post:list-subscribe:list-post:(x)openpgp:(x)autocrypt";
```

It differs from the defaults [specified in rspamd docs](https://rspamd.com/doc/modules/dkim_signing.html#default-sign_headers-after-193) only with "x" on `reply-to` but this shouldn't be the cause, should it?

Any clues why might this be happening or what is the meaning/difference between what I sent and typically receive?

Comment: I tried to clarify, adding more context.

Answer (score 1):

Thats just.. how it works. The [o/x modifier](https://rspamd.com/doc/modules/dkim_signing.html#rules-of-headers-sign) just makes the configuration more versatile, in the presence of at least one such header they both mean "sign it another time", so **having that header name appear twice in the signature is working as configured, and working as it should**.

Signing a header once just means the first header will be checked for changes during transit. Signing a header twice means the first and second header of that name will be checked for changed during transit. Signing a header twice while only having one such header results in a signature where no further header of that name can be inserter without breaking the signature. That [duplication is how you are protected from headers added](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6376#section-5.4) with names of which none further should be inserted.

Such as the `Date` header. It is generally nonsensical to have it appear twice. So signing your header, plus the fact that no second such headers is present (= 2 times), ensures recipients will consider a message with your (and only your) `Date` header correctly signed.

Recommendation: Stick with the rspamd defaults, they provide reasonable guarantees while causing little interoperability problems for common use cases.

Comment: thank you, you write in your comment to the quesion "as documented" - could you be so kind as to link where this is documented? Also I still am unsure I understand this (docs may help) because I see messages coming with signature marked as `h=Date:Subject:From:To;` and I always thought it meant that only listed headers were signed. Then I get confused when I see `from:from` etc. So does that mean that line like `h=Date:Subject:From:To;` is actually incorrect? Or at least not protecting agains insertion of additional headers, which were already signed?

Comment: Signing singletons only once *should* not be a problem, provided mail clients display the fields that have are included in the signature. Some people trust that this is what mail clients will do. Those fools!

Comment: There is no such thing as *"correct"* here. You are merely trading interoperability and message size for the ability to rule out some shenanigans, none of which matter when someone sends validly-signed phishing using the similarly-looking `you@y0urb0ma1n.example`

Comment: In response to recommendation  - I changed the default on `reply-to` from "o" to "x" because while I do not use this header some maling lists I use add it on the way and having it always signed caused verification failures. Changing it to "x" (optionally oversign) solved the problem